# How to convert c# string to c++ string when we pass string as parameter using winapis

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

Using SendMessageW function I am passing c# string as a parameter to c++ function. I am typecasting to CString in c++ but it's value is empty. Please check below code and provide solution

-----------------------c# code ------------------

```
public unsafe IntPtr Testing()
{

  string string_aux = "Stringtochange";
  void* pt = Marshal.StringToBSTR(string_aux).ToPointer();
  IntPtr ab = new IntPtr(pt);
  return ab;
}

public void GetValue()  
{

   SendMessageW(utilityHandle1, TVM_GETITEMHEIGHT, handle,Testing());

}
```

--------------------- C++ code --------------

```
CString *st = (CString*)lParam;

MessageBox(NULL,*st,L"stringvalue",NULL);
```

---

Here *st value is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be abusing `TVM_GETITEMHEIGHT`. Why not use a custom message.

`CString` is a C++ class. It is not binary compatible with a `BSTR`.

Personally I would use `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni` in the C# and cast to `wchar_t*` in the C++. Remember to destroy the unmanaged memory after you've used it when `SendMessageW` returns, by calling `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`.

Comment: I am sending custom message in place of TVM_GETITEMHEIGHT. I am new to c++ I have used Marshal.StringToUni in c# but I  do not know how to convert 'LPARAM' to 'wchar_t*' and to 'CString' Can you please tell c++ code to covert 'LPARAM' to 'CString'

Comment: You do know how to do this. You have the code in your answer. Cast the `lParam` to `wchar_t*`. With `(wchar_t*)lParam`. Or `reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>)(lParam)`. You don't need a `CString` to call `MessageBoxW`.

Comment: He should be able to use `CString s = (const wchar_t*)lParam;`? though it is not necessary unless you need to do some string formatting with `CString`

Comment: I have tried those three but message in MessageBox is coming as empty.c# code is 'IntPtr bn = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni("passingstring");' --- 'SendMessageW(utilityHandle, Win32Utilities.RegisterWindowMessage("requiredcontrol"), handle,bn )' ---Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(bn);-----In C++: wchar_t* cvb = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(lParam); ----- MessageBox(NULL,cvb,L"stringvalue",NULL); ------ here cvb value is empty. Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: And you changed the C# code to call `StringToCoTaskMemUni`?

Comment: That should work. There's something wrong somewhere. Do bear in mind that you did not show a [mcve] so for all we know there's an error elsewhere. Good luck debugging it.